# UIImages as icons in side push menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to preface this by saying I am new to iOS.
I am currently trying to create a side push menu that when clicked on has icons beside each menu item. I currently have the side push menu working with several menu items listed, however, I am really struggling trying to get the images beside each item.
I have written the side push menu and list items programmatically with the code below.

```
import UIKit

class SideMenuTable: UITableViewController {
    let sideMenuImages = [UIImage(named: "Main"), UIImage(named: "Departments"), UIImage(named: "Deliveries"), UIImage(named: "Warehouse"), UIImage(named: "Help")]

    var menu = [Menu]()

    @IBOutlet weak var test: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Change Menu View"

        menu = [
            Menu(title: "Main"),
            Menu(title: "Departments"),
            Menu(title: "Deliveries"),
            Menu(title: "Warehouse"),
            Menu(title: "Help")
        ]
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if tableView.isHidden {
            if let selectionIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: animated)
            }
        } else if tableView.isFocused {
            if let selectionIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPaths, animated: animated)
            }
        }
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menu.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sideCell", for: indexPath)
        let menuSide: Menu


//        var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: ".png")

        menuSide = menu[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel!.text = menuSide.title
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(indexPath.section == 1) {
            if(indexPath.row == 3) {
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Warehouse", sender: self)
            } else {
                NSLog("NO SELECTION AVAILABLE")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the picture below.

[image: ![SidePushMenuViewController]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmO0O.png)

I have started to attempt to solve my problem by inserting a UIImage into the prototype cells.

However, when I connect the UIImage as an outlet into the code above I receive this error. (NOTE: in the code above the outlet is named test)

[image]

It is here where I am getting stuck.
I need to connect this outlet in order to add icons for the various menu items I have.

What am I missing?
Is there a different solution to this problem of creating icons for menu items?

Do I need to create a separate subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom class for UITableviewcell where you need to create IBOutlet to imageview and label.

Now you can access it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView:     UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sideCell", for: indexPath) as YourCustomCell

    let menuSide: Menu
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: ".png")

menuSide = menu[indexPath.row]
cell.customLabel!.text =       menuSide.title

    cell.customLabel?.textAlignment = .center

Cell.imgViewName.image = image
return cell
}
```

Here customLabel and imgViewName is the name of your IBOutlets which you need to drag in you custom cell from storyboard also provide the name of custom cell in your storyboard by selecting that particular cell.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But can you ellaborate on 'create custom class' and 'YourCustomCell', is my current custom cell not already 'sideCell'? Apologies if this is too mundane, as mentioned I am quite new

Comment: @JulianSilvestri For custom cell creation you can follow this tutorial . If any problem then let me know - http://www.apptuitions.com/uitableview-with-custom-cell-in-swift/

Comment: @JulianSilvestri can you show me the complete code that you changed using the link?

Comment: I have used the information you provided and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your not want to create custom class then please set any tag on your uiimageview and uilabel and use as below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView:     UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 


let lblmenu : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel
    lblmenu.text = ArrMenuoption[indexPath.row] as? String
    let img : UIImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(11) as! UIImageView
    img.image = UIImage.init(named: ArrMenuoptionimg[indexPath.row] as! String )
return cell }
```